# Difference between continuity point of a measure and of a function?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I was wondering what the relationship is between a continuity point of a measure and of a function? Or are they even related? A measure is of course a function in itself. Say we are taking the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition of continuity for a function and the definition that $x$ is a point of continuity for the measure $\mu$ if $\mu(\{x\})=0$.

If we consider  the distribution function $F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])$, then if $x$ is a point of continuity is $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} F(x+\epsilon) = F(x)$ or in other words that $F$ is continuous at $x$? Or is this always true?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: @CruZ: In general, a measure is said to be continuous at a point $x_0$ if $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$. In the context of measure on the real line, that is equivalent to continuity of the function $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x[)$ at $x_0$ as you can see for example form noticing that $(x_0-1/n,,x_0+1/n)$ is a sequence of decreasing intervals whose intersection is $\{x_0\}$. Try to convince on your own of this fact, it is worth doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution function $F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])$ is always non-decreasing and right-continuous. On the other hand:

> Let $F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])$. If $F(x)$ is finite at $x$, then $F$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\mu(\{x\})=0$.

**Proof**
$(\Rightarrow)$ Since $F$ is is always non-decreasing, we have, for all $n$,
$$\mu ((x-1/n,x]) = F(x) - F(x-1/n) < \infty$$
Since $\{(x-1/n,x]\}_n$ is a decreasing family of set and $\bigcap_n (x-1/n,x]=\{x\}$, we have
$$ \mu(\{x\})  = \mu \left ( \bigcap_n (x-1/n,x]  \right)= \lim_n  (F(x) - F(x-1/n)) =0$$
$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $a_n$ be any sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$.
Note that $\{(-\infty,x-a_n]\}$ is an increasing family of sets and $\bigcup_n (-\infty,x-a_n] = (-\infty,x)$. So
$$ \lim_n F(x-a_n)= \lim \mu((-\infty,x-a_n])= \mu((-\infty,x))$$
Since this is true for any sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$, we have
$$\lim_{y \to x^-} F(y) = \mu((-\infty,x))$$
Now, if $\mu(\{x\})=0$, then
$$ F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])= \mu((-\infty,x)) + \mu(\{x\}) = \lim_{y \to x^-} F(y) $$
So $F$ is left-continuous on $x$. But we know that  $F$ is right-continuous on $x$. So $F$ is continuous on $x$. $\square$